# Pinch zoom with PDF.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, hammer.js, pdf.js

I have a mobile app that renderes pdfs with PDF.js. My frameworks are Ionic and Angular.
I can render the pdfs, but I have problems with the zooming. When I use the Ionic zoom, the pdf is blurred. PDF.js provides zooming, but just with levels.
Is there a way to combine the pinch gesture and the unblurred zooming?

I tried already hammer.js, but I didn't find working code...

Comment: See also https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/issues/2582

Comment: Thank you. But I have already seen this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution for this:

I rendered the pdf with a factor of 2.3, so the page is too tall. Then I zoomed out with Ionic and calculated the value like this:

```
$ionicScrollDelegate.$getByHandle("pdfScroller")
    .zoomBy(window.innerWidth / (document.getElementById("pageContainer1").clientWidth);
```

The factor 2.3 has to be set in the viewer.js respectively pdf.js.
In line 4900 - 5000 should be something like this:

```
case 'page-width':
    scale = pageWidthScale;
    break;
```

change it to this:

```
case 'page-width':
    scale = pageWidthScale * 2.3;
    break;
```

Now it should be possible to zoom in and the text is readable.

**EDIT**

HTML:

```
<ion-scroll id="pdfScrollerID" zooming="{{!sidebarOpen}}" min-zoom="{{minZoomObject.minZoom}}" overflow-scroll="false" direction="xy" has-bouncing="false" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;" delegate-handle="pdfScroller" class="pdfScrollerStyle" on-swipe-left="nextPage()" on-swipe-right="previousPage()" scrollbar-x="false" scrollbar-y="false" ng-click="closeSidebar()">
    <div id="viewerContainer" style="padding-bottom: 100%; padding-top: 20px;" on-double-tap="resetZoom()">
        <div id="viewer" class="viewer-styles">
        </div>
    </div>
</ion-scroll>
```

Controller (init):

```
pdf = news.getPdf($scope.section, $scope.pdfNumber);

PDFJS.workerSrc = 'lib/pdfviewerx/pdf.worker.js';
PDFJS.getDocument($scope.getPageLink(pdf)).then($scope.getDocAndPdf);

$scope.pdfScroller = $ionicScrollDelegate.$getByHandle("pdfScroller");
$scope.littlePdfScroller = $ionicScrollDelegate.$getByHandle("littlePdfScroller");


container = document.getElementById('viewerContainer');
viewer = document.getElementById('viewer');

//var pdfLinkService = new PDFLinkService();


pdfViewer = new PDFViewer({
  container: container,
  viewer: viewer,
  showPage: $scope.activePageIndex + 1,
  scaleFactor : 2.3
});

$scope.pdfFindController = new PDFFindController({
  pdfViewer: pdfViewer
});

pdfViewer.setFindController($scope.pdfFindController);

container.addEventListener('pagesinit', function () {
    pdfViewer.currentScaleValue = 'page-width';                            
});

// Loading document.
PDFJS.getDocument($scope.getPageLink(pdf)).then(function (pdfDocument) {

    documentPdf = pdfDocument;
    pdfViewer.setDocument(pdfDocument, pageRendered);
    $ionicLoading.show({
        template: '<ion-spinner icon="ios" id="loadingSpinner"></ion-spinner>'
    });
    //pdfLinkService.setDocument(pdfDocument, null);
});

zoomToFitPage();
```

zoomToFitPage():

```
function zoomToFitPage(){       
$timeout(function() {
    if(document.getElementById("pageContainer1") != undefined){
        zoomToFullSize();
        $timeout(function(){ 
            $scope.minZoomObject.minZoom = $scope.pdfScroller.getScrollPosition().zoom;
            $scope.$apply();                
            setPdfToCenter();
        , 500);     
    } else{
        zoomToFitPage();
    }
}, 500);
}
```

setPdfToCenter and ZoomToFullSize:

```
function setPdfToCenter(){
     var scroll = document.getElementsByClassName("scroll");
     for(var i=0; i < scroll.length; i++){
          if(scroll[i].parentElement.id == "pdfScrollerID"){
               scroll[i].style.width = (window.innerWidth / MINZOOM_DEAULT) + "px";
          }
     }
     $scope.resetZoom(); 
}

function zoomToFullSize(){
    $scope.pdfScroller.zoomBy(window.innerWidth / (document.getElementById("pageContainer1").clientWidth));
}
```

Comment: I'm having problems trying to achieve what you describe, could you provide some working code? are you rendering the pdf inside the ion-scroll directive?

Comment: Yes, I rendered it in an ion-scroll named "pdfScroller". I add some code. But I switched to the cordova document viewer plugin, because the my pdf viewer was not good enough. I had many memory problems. Maybe it's a possibility for you, too.

Comment: Nice I'll try, actually I couldn't make it work because there is a bug in the latest versions of ionic that requires overflow-scroll="false" attribute to be added to the directive, otherwise the zoom feature doesn't work.
https://github.com/saravmajestic/ionic/issues/34#issuecomment-183564051